# How to get input from bash terminal into my program

Tags: c, bash, c99

**One of my assignments has the following question:**

> One function (function #2) of your program is to read in the content of an instance  file.  To read in
>   the  file "
>   instance10
>   001.txt
>   " you will execute the command:
>
> NameOfProgram -i instance10
>   001.txt
>
> Here "
>   -i " is the command-line option that indicates the succeeding argument is the
>   input  filename.

**This is what I have done so far, mostly a skeleton:**

```
/* Assignment 1 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 

{

  FILE *fp;

  int max_x, max_y, num_pt, rand_inst;
  int *x_coordinate, *y_coordinate;

  int inputfile = 0, outputfile = 0;
  int i;

  if (argc == 1)
    {
      /* to generate random instances, accepting parameters from stdin */
      printf("Generating random instances...");
      printf("Enter the circuit board size MAX_X MAX_Y:  ");
      scanf("%d %d", &max_x, &max_y);
      printf("Enter the number of points NUM_PT:  ");
      scanf("%d", &num_pt);
      printf("Enter the number of random instances to be generated:  ");
      scanf("%d", &rand_inst);
      return 1;
    }
  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
      if (strcmp (argv[i], "-i") == 0)
          inputfile = i+1;
      else if (strcmp (argv[i], "-o") == 0)
          outputfile = i+1;
    }
  if (inputfile == 0)
    {
      /* invalid comman line options */
      printf("\nIncorrect command-line\n");
      printf("myprogram [-i inputfile [-o outputfile]]");
      return -1;
    }

  **/* THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP */**
  if (inputfile == 1)
    {
      fp = fopen(/*Name of the input file (instance10_001.txt) */, "r")
    }


  if ((fp = fopen(argv[inputfile], "r")) == NULL)
    {
      /* open file error */
      return -2;
    }
  while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &max_x) != 1)
    {
      if (ferror(fp))
        {
          /* read error */
          fclose(fp);
          return -3;
        }
      if (feof(fp))
        {
          /* no integer to read */
          fclose(fp);
          return -4;
        }
      fscanf(, "%*[^\n]"); /*skip the rest of line */
    }
  if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &max_y) != 1)
    {
      /* max_y not following max_x */
      fclose(fp);
      return -5;
    }
  while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &num_pt) != 1)
    {
      if(ferror(fp))
       {
          /* read error */
          fclose(fp);
          return -6;
        }
      if (feof(fp))
        {
          /* no integer to read */
          fclose(fp);
          return -7;
        }
       fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]"); /* skip the rest of line */
    }

  x_coordinate = (int *)malloc(num_pt * sizeof(int));
  y_coordinate = (int *)malloc(num_pt * sizeof(int));
  for (i = 0; i < num_pt; i++) 
    {
      while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &x_coordinate[i]) != 1) 
        {
          if (ferror(fp)) 
            {
              /* read error */
              fclose(fp);
              return -8;
            }


if (feof(fp)) 
        {
          /* no integer to read */
          fclose(fp);
          return -9;
        }
      fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]"); /* skip the rest of line */
    }
      if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &y_coordinate[i]) != 1) 
    {
      /* y_coordinate not following x_coordinate */
      fclose(fp);
      return -10;
    }
    }
  fclose(fp);
  if (outputfile > 0) 
    {
    if ((fp = fopen(argv[outputfile], "w")) == NULL) 
      {
    /* open file error */
    return -2;
      }
    fprintf(fp, "##################################################\n");
    fprintf(fp, "#%s\n", argv[inputfile]);
    fprintf(fp, "#area [0, MAX_X] x [0, MAX_Y]\n");
    fprintf(fp, "%d\t%d\n", max_x, max_y);
    fprintf(fp, "#number of points NUM_PT\n");
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n", num_pt);
    fprintf(fp, "#coordinates\n");
    for (i = 0; i < num_pt; i++) 
      {
    fprintf(fp, "%d\t%d\n", x_coordinate[i], y_coordinate[i]);
      }
    fprintf(fp, "#end of instance\n");
    fclose(fp);
    }
  else 
    {
      printf("##################################################\n");
      printf("#%s\n", argv[inputfile]);
      printf("#area [0, MAX_X] x [0, MAX_Y]\n");
      printf("%d\t%d\n", max_x, max_y);
      printf("#number of points NUM_PT\n");
      printf("%d\n", num_pt);
      printf("#coordinates\n");
      for (i = 0; i < num_pt; i++) 
    {
      printf("%d\t%d\n", x_coordinate[i], y_coordinate[i]);
    }
      printf("#end of instance\n");
    }
  free(x_coordinate);
  free(y_coordinate);

  return 0;
}
```

***I am wondering how I can read the name of the input file from bash terminal. Should I use scanf?***

***how do I get what the user has inputted as the input file? Like for example if the user is running my program from bash with `./myprogram -i instance10_001.txt`, how can I open the inputted file in my program?***

**PS I am using my Ubuntu terminal to access my lab computer via ssh.**

**Language: c99 ; Compiler: gcc**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a simple error in your if statment. You're saying if, and only if, inputfile is 1 (which means -o must have been argv[0]) it will open inputfile.

```
  if (inputfile == 0)
    {
      /* invalid command line options */
      printf("\nIncorrect command-line\n");
      printf("myprogram [-i inputfile [-o outputfile]]");
      return -1;
    }
  else /* if inputfile is not equal to 0, then this will execute. */
    {
      fp = fopen(argv[inputfile], "r");
    }
```

Also, there's another problem here, in which you assign fp to a function and then reopen the file already opened in fp:

```
/* removed fp = fopen (a function) */
  if (fp == NULL) /* You already opened the file; no need to open again until fclose */
    {
      /* open file error */
      return -2;
    }
```

Also, in this block of code:

```
      while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &x_coordinate[i]) != 1) 
        {
          if (ferror(fp)) 
            {
              /* read error */
              fclose(fp);
              return -8;
            }


if (feof(fp)) 
        {
          /* no integer to read */
          fclose(fp);
          return -9;
        }
      fscanf(fp, "%*[^\n]"); /* skip the rest of line */
    }
```

Fscanf returns the number of arguments successfully filled, which in this case, will always be 1.
Note that similar problems may be present in the remainder of the code.

Comment: The first `if` statement checks if the user entered the correct command line that is either `myprogram -i inputfile -o outputfile` or vice versa. If the user inputs for say `myprogram -z inputfile -o outputfile` it will print the error and exit.

Comment: @ImtiazRaqib: I know, however when you type `if (inputfile == 1)`, the fopen will only happen if the inputfile == 1, in which case it must be the first argument on the command line:  

In `./a.out -i file`,  

./a.out is argument 0, -i is argument 1, and file is argument 2, and therefore inputfile will be 2.

Comment: Taken I change my if statement, how do I get what the user has inputted as the input file? Like for example if the user is running my program from bash with `./myprogram -i instance10_001.txt`, how can I open the inputted file in my program?

Comment: `argv[inputfile]`, you did it right. `fp=fopen(<filename>,"r");` opens <filename> with read access and stores the file pointer into fp. Once you have opened it once, until you run `fclose(fp);`, the file pointer will always be stored in `fp`.

Comment: argv[inputfile] will give me the user inputted filename?

Comment: argv is an array of string pointers which for a single argument. Your inputfile variable stores the argument number of the input file specified. So, argv[inputfile] will give the user inputted filename.